# Confusion with void* type memory allocation?

Tags: c++

I am pretty inexperienced in C++ programming and now I'm trying to make a small program using dctmk to modify the pixel data of the dicom image. In doing so while reading documentation I found a c++ method about which I'm not quite clear. In the documention for the class [DicomImage](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/classDicomImage.html#a82a21140461aececd0a6dcd68466f40) I found the following method:

```
int DicomImage::getOutputData   (   void *      buffer,
        const unsigned long     size,
        const int   bits = 0,
        const unsigned long     frame = 0,
        const int   planar = 0   
    )
```

My confusion is about `buffer`. It's quoted in the link as

> buffer :    pointer to memory buffer (must already be allocated)

Here my confusion is how do a I allocate? I'm not sure how I could allocate a memory that's a pointer of void type. Could you please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't forget to choose one of the answers as accepted if it solves your problem. It will help further readers to find solutions to their problems quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following way (for example):

```
void * mem = malloc(1024); // 1 kb

image.GetOutputData(mem, 1024);

// Don't forget to free(mem);
```

Another way:

```
char * mem = new char[1024];

image.GetOutputData((void *)mem, 1024);

// Don't forget to delete[] mem;
```

Another way:

```
char mem[1024];

image.GetOutputData((void *)&mem, 1024);
```

Comment: seems like char[1024] is a c# feature

Comment: in this case do you need to delete mem ? char mem[1024];

Answer (score 4):

A pointer to `void` can point to anything, it's a generic nondescript anonymous pointer to some memory. This means that you can pass any kind of pointer as the first argument of the function, as all pointers can implicitly be converted to `void*`.

Comment: Now I'm doing the following:

`void* buffer;
buffer=(void*)malloc(sizeofdata);`

Is that Okay?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to cast results of malloc to void *, because malloc AFAIR already returns void *

Comment: @the_naive - although `malloc` is OK, it's only really there for C compatibility. The C++ equivalent is `new char [sizeofdata]` - allocating an array of characters (effectively bytes). When you deallocate, use `mfree` for `malloc`, or `delete[]` for that style of `new` (you have to use `delete[]` to free arrays, but `delete` without the `[]` to free single values).

Comment: @the_naive - however, arguably using `void*` is C-style code anyway, so using `malloc` and `mfree` may actually make more sense than `new` and `delete` for this.

Comment: I'd argue for `std::vector<char>` over `new[]`. There is no reason to use a primitive C API just to match the primitive Dicom API.

Comment: @Steve314 `mfree`? You mean just `free` I hope?

Comment: @Joachim - sorry - it's been a while since I used them.

Comment: @the_naive I recommend you use smart pointers such as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers. And also that you as much as possible refrain from using void pointer in your own program. So the allocation look something like `std::unique_ptr<char> buffer(new char[sizeofdata]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate any type of buffer. It will be converted using void*. However you will need to pass proper size of element. You will need to refer to documentation of api for size of each buffer element. In the example below it is 1 byte. And total buffer size is 10.

```
int size_of_buffer = 10;
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*size_of_buffer);
```

Comment: You have to cast results of malloc to unsigned char *, because AFAIR malloc returns plain void *.

Comment: I would avoid using `malloc` unless it is required for compatibility with a C based API. Prefer`new` and `delete` and avoid the casting and size calculations. `uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[size_of_buffer];` is shorter, more intuitive and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `DicomImage::getOutputData` does not care how you allocated your bytes.  Simply take take the pointer to some blob of your choice (object, struct, array, whatever) and cast it to `void*`.    You can get the memory with `new`, `malloc` or it can be a local variable.

Thing to be sure of:

- Make sure you allocate enough space.
- Make sure you accurately send the `size` parameter.
- Make sure that you understand what format of data `DicomImage::getOutputData` works with.